# QT Creator how to create library from source and use it in a project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, lib

I have a project created and now I wish to write a xlsx file(not csv as I need multiple sheets)

I am trying to use https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexlsx/files/ in my project to accomplish this.

I have downloaded the source, opened the CMakeLists.txt in QT Creator and built it using the MinGW compiler(its the one I am using in my main project). This was difficult as it was trying to use ninja however I adjusted the kit parameters and finally got it to build.

In the build directory it produces a libSimpleXlsxd.a file.

I then moved this file to my project directory and added this line to my .pro file:

```
LIBS += "C:\path where directory is\libSimpleXlsxd.a"
```

I have tried adding INCLUDEPATH to the project directory as will with no luck.

Now I have run into a wall as I am unable to include anything from the lib in my project.  Something seems to be broken or missing along the way to link things and I cannot figure it out. I have tried adding INCLUDEPATH to the project directory as will with no luck. I have searched the web for hours and am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
for clarification: the libSimpleXlsxd.a is in my project directory(.pro location). I have tried using the absolute path in both the INCLUDEPATH and LIB and the $$PWD shortcut. Neither worked as I still cannot include.

Thanks

Comment: ***I have tried adding INCLUDEPATH to the project directory as will with no luck*** I believe this is the step you need to fix. Since you gave no details on what you tried or how it failed its difficult to help.

Comment: Sorry thought that was clear, added INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

Comment: I believe $$PWD would not be the correct path.. Maybe its: `C:\path where directory is\` maybe there is an include folder inside that. I don't know what your file structure looks like.

Comment: The location of `libSimpleXlsxd.a` has nothing to do with the folder containing the headers. Where is the folder containing the headers located on your hard drive? When you built the library did you build the INSTALL target? If so where did it install the headers?

Comment: I am not sure(bit out of my league) I just built it through QT Creator by opening the CMakeLists.txt. This produced a folder structure with the library in the top level. I ONLY moved the library over though

Comment: If you did not build the INSTALL target, the folder that you need to include may just be the folder containing the source code for the library. You probably should spend some time with the file explorer in your OS to look for the correct folder.

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly, I need to include header files as well as the library?

Comment: Yes, the `.a` file does not give you any type of access to the headers. You need to add the location of the headers to your INCLUDEPATH. You can copy them to your project folder possibly. Be careful however if a folder name is specified in the #include you will have to keep the same folder structure as the source code.